# gSoap: simultaneous usage of several header files with soapcpp2

Tags: c++, gsoap

I am currently using gSoap's `soapcpp2` for generating XML serializer/deserializers for my own data types.

I simply define my type in a header file and then I submit it to `soapcpp2` using the following command line:

```
soapcpp2 -e -j myheader.h
```

**ATTENTION**: the header file does not come from `wsdl2h` (another tool provided by gSoap) but instead it is handwritten.

This produces (among the others) the files `soapH.h` and `soapC.c` which actually are the header and the implementation of such serializer/deserializers.

Now let's suppose I want to do that on two distinct header files (call them `myheader1.h` and `myheader2.h`): both of them will produce their own `soapH.h` and `soapC.c` but I need to link both versions of them in my executable code... How can I do that?

Isn't there an option to let `soapcpp2` to customize the name of `soapH.h` and `soapC.c`?

Am I completely wrong and there is a better approach to this issue?

Answer (score 1):

At the end I came up in using `soapcpp2` standard input... So for example if I have two header files to be processed by `soapcpp2` at the same time then I issue the following command (on Linux):

```
cat header1.h header2.h > soapcpp2 -e -j
```